# How to make ansible only ask for become password when required

Tags: ansible

I am using ansible 2.0.2.0 to update my static website from any computer. My playbook runs on localhost only and essentially has two parts:

- Privileged part: Ensure packages are installed, essentially `apt` tasks with `become: true`
- Unprivileged part: Fill in templates, minify and sync with web hosting service, essentially `command` tasks without `become`.

I would prefer having these two parts in the same playbook so that I do not need to worry about dependencies when switching computers. Ideally, I would like ansible to check if the `apt` packages are installed and only ask for the become password if it needs to install any.

Other, less satisfactory alternatives that I have explored so far and their drawbacks are highlighted below:

- `sudo ansible-playbook ...`: Runs the unprivileged part as `root`, asks sudo password when not required;
- `ansible-playbook --ask-become-pass ...`: Always asks sudo password, even if no new packages need to be installed;
- `ansible-playbook ...`: Fails with `sudo: a password is required`.

Is there any way to keep the privileged and unprivileged parts in the same playbook without needlessly typing the sudo password nor giving needless privileges to the unprivileged part?

Comment: I think in order for ansible to use apt to check if the package dependencies are met it would need root permissions - so even if no new packages need to be installed you would need to pass the password.

Comment: same issue, not solved yet

Comment: guess you will have to use the shell module for this instead of a package module. A little hackish. A better way would be to separate out these playbooks

Answer (score 5):

If you run `ansible-playbook` with the `--ask-sudo-pass` parameter, then your second option will ask you for the password once, and will reuse that each time, where needed.

If do run as sudo as in your first case, then you can use become within the script, to lose your privilege status, as you need it.

However, you can setup `ansible.cfg` to do remote installs to `localhost`.  Hence you can setup an unprivileged ansible user (I use `centos`), which is setup to `sudo` without needing a password. Then I setup my local user in the `authorized_keys` for the `centos` user.

Hence you run unprivileged (as `centos`), but when you need to sudo, you can use `become_method: sudo` to become root.

Using this method I do bare metal installs with the same ansible playbook, as I do remote AWS installs.

Looking at my `ansible.cfg` I have:-

```
[defaults]
hostfile = inventory
# use local centos account, and ask for sudo password
remote_user = centos
#ask_pass = true
#private_key_file = ~/packer/ec2_amazon-ebs.pem
```

My `inventory.yml` contains:-

```
[webservers]
  localhost
```

my `setup.sh` contains:-

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -vvv
#ansible-playbook --ask-sudo-pass playbook.yml
```

Hence all password asking statements are off.  Remember as I don't specify a `private_key_file` in the defaults, it assumes the running user has authority to ssh to `centos@localhost` without requiring a password

Comment: Not sure but now it is `--ask-become` instead `--ask-sudo-pass`